# Specify current directory as codebase in JNLP File

Tags: java, jnlp, java-web-start

My Jar file that I am trying to launch is in the same directory as the JNLP file.
How do I specify that in my `codebase` attribute?

```
<jnlp codebase="file://" href="launch.jnlp" spec="1.0+">
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an example JNLP using `codebase`, setting up a desktop icon and splash
    screen. See the oracle page Structure of the JNLP file, and earlier document: 
    Java Network Launching Protocol and API Specification (JSR-56) is very thorough.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- JNLP File for YourWebstart -->
<jnlp
 spec="1.5+"
 codebase="http://YourWebsiteurl.com/YourWeblaunchPage"
 href=”Your.jnlp">
 <information>
   <title>YourPrograms</title>
   <vendor>YourCompany</vendor>
   <description>Your application</description>
   <description kind="short">Your weblaunch description</description>
   <icon href="YourdesktopIconLogo.png"/>
   <icon kind="splash" href="YourSplashScreenImage.png"/>
   <shortcut online="true">
     <desktop/>
   </shortcut>  
  </information>
  <security>
    <all-permissions/>
  </security>
  <resources>
    <j2se version="1.6+" 
    href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se"/>    
    <jar href="YourApplication.jar"/>
  </resources>
  <application-desc main-class="YourMainClassLocation.YourMainClass">
   <argument>AnyArgumentsYouWantToPassIntoYourApplication</argument>
 </application-desc>
</jnlp>
```

Answer (score 2):

A file based `codebase` will not work at time of deployment, and during development, a web based code base can be overridden at run-time.

To get the file based URL for testing, create a `File` object in the directory of interest, the JNLP file would probably be best.  Check that the `file.exists()` (very important to check our assumptions), then call `file.toURI().toURL()` to get it as a file base URL.

Also, be sure to check the JNLP using [JaNeLA](https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/folders/0B5B9wDXIGw9lUnJaUjA2cmlVRE0).

Answer (score 1):

The answer marked as correct is correct when you use a web server, but if you use the file system the following must be used in order to use the current directory as codebase

```
<jnlp href="launch.jnlp" spec="1.0+">
```

This works using jdk 1.7.0_25